# Add a class to a DIV with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Example HTML:

```
<div id="foo" class="class_one"></div>
```

How can I add the class `class_two` without replacing `class_one`?

end result:

```
<div id="foo" class="class_one class_two"></div>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

See deekshith's answer below if you only need to support new browsers

Standard javascript:

```
document.getElementById('foo').className += ' class_two'
```

or JQuery:

```
$('#foo').addClass('class_two');
```

Answer (score 21):

You may use jQuery.

```
$('#YourElement').addClass('YourClass'); //add

$('#YourElement').removeClass('YourClass'); //remove

$('#YourElement').toggleClass('YourClass'); //toggle
```

---

Or Javascript, if you wish.

```
document.getElementById('id').classList.add('YourClass'); //add
document.getElementById('id').classList.remove('YourClass'); //remove
```

Comment: classList is available on most modern browsers monhttp://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist

Answer (score 18):

A better way to add a class would be to use [Element.classList.add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Examples):

```
document.getElementById('foo').classList.add("class_two");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make life easier with a couple of helper functions:

```
function addClass(el, className) {
  var classes = el.className.match(/\S+/g) || [];  

  if (!hasClass(el, className)) {
    classes.push(className);
  }
  el.className = classes.join(' ');
}

function hasClass(el, className) {
  var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + className + '(\\s+|$)');
  return re.test(el.className);
}

addClass(document.getElementById('foo'), 'bar')
```