# Add class to html element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('myId').classList.add('myClass');
</script>
```

How to alter it and add `myClass` into `#myId a` element? I have single `anchor` element there:

```
<div id="myId">
    <a href="#" title="link">Add class to me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('myId').className`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444640/add-a-class-to-a-div-with-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a class to a given element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Comment: Is there only a single `a` element inside `#myId`? Or are there multiple? Do you want to add the class to all of them?

Comment: unless you're using jQuery (or any other third party library that supports such bindings), you most likely are forced to iterate through all the <a> elements of your myId dom element, unless you only have a single <a> element in your myId.

Comment: i have only one a element there

Comment: Then @MrVentzi 's answer below is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your question, you want to target the anchor tag and set the class there, so:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('one');
var anchor = parent.getElementsByTagName("A")[0];
anchor.classList.add('myClass');
```

That should do it.

If you have multiple anchor tags you can loop through them.

```
var parent = document.getElementById('one');
var anchorList = parent.getElementsByTagName("A");

for(i = 0; i < anchorList.length; i++) {
    anchorList[i].classList.add('myClass');
}
```

Comment: That's it, but it's still unclear whether the OP has a single or multiple `a` elements.

Comment: @MrVentzi +1 Good Answer..Probably You should add Browser Compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility in your answer as well

Comment: In case of a single element, this is a bit shorter: `document.querySelector('#one a').classList.add(...)`

Answer (score -1):

to add class name you use

```
document.getElementById('myId').className="Your class name";
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to target the OP's issue at all.

Comment: This targets the wrong element and overwrites any classes already set.