# My javascript only works on the first div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write this javascript function so that when I hover on the image the title changes its color. I got it to work but for some reasons it only works for the first div...maybe my scoping is wrong?

Thanks!

```
<body>
    <div>
      <a href="" id="img"><img src="http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg" class="img" width="200"></a>
      <a href="" id="head1"><h1>test title</h1></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="" id="img"><img src="http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg" class="img" width="200"></a>
      <a href="" id="head1"><h1>test title</h1></a>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var image = document.getElementById("img");
var text1 = document.getElementById("head1");

function textRed() {
    text1.style.color = 'red';
};

function textDefault() {
    text1.style.color = 'blue';
};

image.onmouseover = function(){
  textRed()
};

image.onmouseout = function(){
  textDefault()
};

</script>
```

Comment: ID is unique SIR! so you can not have it twice on the same Document. and youshall use add/remove class or css

Comment: AHhhh...no wonder! Is there a add/remove class function in javascript?

Comment: To use script for this is really to go the wrong way, css has a built-in function for this, _hover_, still, here is a post showing how to change a class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444640/add-a-class-to-a-div-with-javascript

Comment: @PatrickC yes check Element.classList - Web APIs     https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 3):

You should never use multiple elements with the same ID's. Use classes instead and then in JS:

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName("img");
var text1 = document.getElementsByClassName("head1");
```

The HTML then becomes:

```
<body>
    <div>
      <a href="" class="img"><img src="http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg" class="img" width="200"></a>
      <a href="" class="head1"><h1>test title</h1></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="" class="img"><img src="http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg" class="img" width="200"></a>
      <a href="" class="head1"><h1>test title</h1></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Probably because it returns an array which you then need to loop through. I would suggest using the method provided by LGSon since CSS is more than sufficient in achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

For this you can (and should) use css only.

```css
a h1 {
  color: blue
}
a:hover ~ a h1 {
  color: red
}
```

```html
    <div>
      <a href="" id="img1"><img src="http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg" class="img" width="200"></a>
      <a href="" id="head1"><h1>test title</h1></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="" id="img2"><img src="http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg" class="img" width="200"></a>
      <a href="" id="head2"><h1>test title</h1></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept of having an ID is to be able to uniquely identify something. Since you want to group a bunch of *HTML* elements then you need to use `classes`.

So, use the following *JavaScript* function to get an array of all the elements with that `ClassName`.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ClassName")
```

So, then you must loop through each element and add your functions. But, the code will not look the way you have it. There are two simple ways to implement this.

---

Using your design of having a function that is called could look like the following:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ClassName")
for(var i in elements) {
    // Used to prevent a scoping problem where each element becomes the same.
    (function(elem) {
    elem.mouseover = function() {
        // Sets the color of that element. (Green's my favorite color... Sorry...)
        elem.style.color = 'green';
    }
    )(elements[i]);
}
```

---

Now, another way is to use the fact that when the `mouseover` event is triggered the scope of the function is the element. This means `this` is the element that is being interacted with.

```
...
function setColor() {
    this.style.color = `green`;
}
for(var i in elements) {
    // Nicer way...
    elements[i].mouseover = setColor;
    // Or can do something similar to what you are doing:)
    elements[i].mouseover = function() {
        // Calls the setColor function in the correct scope:)
        setColor.call(this);
    }
}
```

---

Now, I know your question was for *JavaScript* but it would be better to use *CSS* to do this.

```
a.ClassName {
    color: yellow;/* Default Color. Not needed unless you want to have a special color. */
}
a.ClassName:hover {
    color: green; /* Assigns the color on mouseover. */
}
```

Hope this helps!!