# Changing color of textbox and adding text on Javascript validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, dom

So I'm trying to validate a form and I'm not being able to get the textbox change when the validation fails. Instead, the form gets completed. What I want is if the validation fails, the textbox border becomes color red and a text in red just below the textbox which says "Fill our this field!"

Here's what I have written just for the purpose of testing and it's not working and I'm not sure how to add the red=colored text just after the box concerned:

```
<form id="reg" method="POST" action="user.php" onsubmit="return validate()">

    <label for="first">First Name: </label>
    <input id="first" name="first" type="text" value="">

    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form> 


function validate(){
    var formIsValid = true;

    if(first.value === ""){
        //Not sure how to add Red-Colored Text below the box which says "Fill our this field!"
        first.borderColor = "red"; //NOT WORKING
        formIsValid = false;    
    }

    return formIsValid;

}
```

Comment: Have you omitted the `<script>...</script>` tags around your function?

Comment: @Graham No The function is in an external javascript file and it's called in the HTML head

Comment: It looks like you're trying to reference the element's id without using the document.getElementById function. Instead of referencing "first" reference document.getElementById("first").

Comment: i used var first = document.getElementById("first") before using it in the function. It should be working, but it's not.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is what you are looking for,

http://jsfiddle.net/F8H7Y/

```
<form name= "reg" id="reg" method="POST" action="user.php" onsubmit="return validate()">

    <label for="first">First Name: </label>
    <input id="first" name="first" type="text" value="">

    <input type="submit">Register</button>
</form> 



function validate(){
    var formIsValid = true;
    var first=document.forms["reg"]["first"];
    if(first.value == null || first.value == ""){
        first.style.borderColor = "red";
        formIsValid = false;    
    }

    return formIsValid;

}
```

Comment: Why use var first=document.forms["reg"]["first"]; INSTEAD OF var first = document.getElementById("first") and it's working perfectly now. I think opera needs the || thing to work for some reason, which I don't know. And my last question to you, how to you make a text appear just below the textbox which say "Fill this textbox, it's important!"?

Thanks :)

Comment: document.getElementById is fine. Both will yield the same thing. As for the error msg, you could either add another hidden div and make it visible on validation failure. Or you could use the same "first" and set a value on it. Look @ http://jsfiddle.net/F8H7Y/1/

Comment: I tried this and it's awesome. I managed to create a new div, append a paragraph to the div and append specific error messages to the paragraph depending on the error. So I simply made an error function but it keeps creating a node whenever i keep clicking the button which is a bad thing. It also breaks my beautiful html page and I'm not sure how to style it up. If you could show me an example, I would appreciate it. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Do not create Divs everytime you click. Precreate a div in HTML along with your form code. and just set the innerHTML property on that div in the validation failure logic.

Comment: Even if I create a new div, when I click the button again and again, won't it keep adding up to the div?

For example: I make a "p" node in the div which says "First Name field not filled in"; and then I don't fill the field and click the button again, won't it create another exact same node just under the node it previously created?

Comment: nope. you are not clear yet.. after the <form></form> add a <div id="error_msg></div> in HTML.. Now from javascript, the place where you return false in validation, just set document.getElementById("error_msg").innerHTML = "Error Message". This element is static on the page. You are neither creating it dynamically, nor deleting it. It is not created when you click submit. It pre-exists.. Just that it has no content - so it doesn't show up. It shows up when innerHTML is filled.

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782857/changing-textbox-border-colour-using-javascript)

I think for text, you can use empty **lable** to  make a text appear just below the textbox which say "Fill this textbox" on validation failure.

Comment: Looking into it :) Thanks