# Can't set css property to an object property in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, local-storage

I'm trying to change the color of the product(object) title based on the current year.
I mean if the product's year is the same as the current year it should change the title color.
Whenever I save, I get an Error in DevTools:
"  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined  ".

```
  <form id="theForm">
   <div>
     <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Type title...">
   </div>
   <div>
     <input type="date" id="date">
   </div>

   <button type="submit" id="sub">Add</button>
 </form>

 <section class="result">
   <div id="addedProducts"></div>
 </section>
```

```
const theForm = document.getElementById("theForm");
theForm.addEventListener("submit", saveProduct);

function saveProduct(evt){
  const proTitle = document.getElementById("title").value;
  const proDate = document.getElementById("date").value;

  const product = {
    title: proTitle,
    date: proDate
  }
    if(localStorage.getItem("products") === null){
      const products = []; //initialized
      products.push(product);// add a new Product
      //to local localStorage
      localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
    } else {
      // get products from localStorage
      const products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));
      // add product to products
      products.push(product);
      // set again to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
    }
    theForm.reset();
    fetchProducts();
    evt.preventDefault()
}
function fetchProducts(){
  const products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));

  const addedProducts = document.getElementById("addedProducts");

  addedProducts.innerHTML = "";

  products.forEach(addProduct);
  function addProduct(product) {

    const title = product.title;
    const date = product.date;

    const splitDate = date.split("");
    const splittedYear = splitDate.slice(0, 4);
    const splittedMonth = splitDate.slice(5, 7);
    const splittedDay = splitDate.slice(8);
    const jYear = splittedYear.join("");
    const jMonth = splittedMonth.join("");
    const jDay = splittedDay.join("");
    const jDate = jMonth +"/"+ jDay +"/"+
        jYear;
    // Parsed Date attributes
    const pYear = parseInt(jYear, 10);
    const pMonth = parseInt(jMonth, 10);
    const pDay = parseInt(jDay, 10);
    // current Date
    const cDate = new Date();
    const cDay = cDate.getDate();
    const cMonth = cDate.getMonth() + 1;
    const cYear = cDate.getFullYear();

    //Here's the problem!!!
        if(pYear == cYear){
        // The next line broke every thing
    /* Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
     set property 'color' of undefined*/
            title.style.color = "#159";
            console.log("yes");//that works fine
        } else {
          console.log("not");// So da that one
        }

  addedProducts.innerHTML += '<div class="res">'+
                                  '<span class="title">' + title +'</span>' +
                                  " " + '<span class="dateClass">' + jDate +'</span>'+
                                  '<button onclick="deletePro(\'' + title + '\',\'' + date + '\')" id="remove">Delete</button>' +
                                 '</div>';
 }
}
```

Sorry if it's a long code. I've been so confused!

Comment: The title variable is a string in this context not a text box. Try something like document.forms[0].elements[‘title’].style.border=‘1px solid red’;

Comment: I did it. And it still doesn't work. It shows another Error: SyntaxError Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: I forgot this way you have to specify name=‘title’ attribute on the text box. You can also do it your way with id=‘title’ attribute https://stackoverflow.com/a/13392847/10634638

Comment: @Jimmy why do you have a function after getElementById in a const? remove the function name.  (It wouldn't be a constant if it's variable anyway)

Comment: @Rachel I wanted to set the value of each input to the product object. I changed it to let. It shouldn't be a const. Thanks for your suggest.